# Automating posts from "company" for the Facebook page of said "company"

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I put *company* in between quotations because my question relates to our Rugby team page but in Facebook it acts like a *company* page.

I am currently rebuilding my teams website ([BBRFC Celtic](http://bbrfc-celtic.be/)) and I am going to add a user login system which will have coaches and admin staff with different levels of *authority*.

Sometimes due to weather conditions, events, or other things a training time may be changed or a match canceled or other various events. When these happen we normally send emails through a mailing list or sms or post on Facebook by hand.

What I want to have is a little bot of some kind that runs behind the scenes of the server and when coaches or admins change something it allows them to make an automated post to Facebook.

Something like after changing a trainings time it asking **Would you like this to be posted to the facebook page and groups?**.

I have been unsuccessful in finding out how I would go about writing the code for this. Our webpage will use `php` but maybe this can be done with `javascript`?

Do I need to get a key to post something as if I were the page?
How about to the different groups we have?

Any pointers would be helpful since I am totally stuck not really programmatically but more conceptually, I do not know if this is even possible.

Comment: Have a look at the facebook API. You wil have to require the person to log in on your page with facebook and then you can programatically do those things with the API. The API is very well documented, hence it should not be too difficult.

Comment: So the server can't be connected "continuously" to the teams facebook? as in, would they have to log in every single time it posts something?

Comment: No you won't have to log in every time you want to post something on facebook, once logged in a cookie is stored. Hence for some time you won't have to reconnect. I'm not able to post a full answer now, however, i can answer your post this evening.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean :/ Im just looking for a more behind the scenes kinda bot, like if I have a certain access key for the page given by the pages admin I should be able to post, since I want it to post not as the person doing it but as if the rugby team itself posted it, you see what I mean? Its basically so that the person doing it just goes YES and thats it, since the person will only use it once each time he goes there the cookie will have probably already died out

Comment: the people going to be doing the whole changed times are not that young most of the time in our team and are not exactly happy with having to do too much hassle (yes they would consider that a hassle) so I am looking for something very hidden with practically no user input except for a yes. Its very demanding sorry haha its just that if not they will just be like: "bah, ill write it myself better" but then they forget most of the time....

Comment: Indeed, the cookie will have died out. If i'm right you can add the necessary persons as administrators of the page (company) and with the api it should be possible to post in name of the page. Furthermore if you remember your password it should be almost a one click thing :)

Comment: From what i understand it seems they will have to log in no matter what (since there are different levels of authority). Hence, the facebook login could replace the regular login so that it does not introduce an extra step. Afterwards it can be a "one click thing" like you want.

Comment: Ill try this out then, thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain the steps you need to accomplish your goal for a website. Note that the documentation also explains the case of a mobile application and others. I used the facebook API before, however, not to manage groups/pages, hence, this post will only point you in the right direction. I will explain how to post a message as being the admin of the page, not sure if you meant facebook pages or groups.

First, the user need to log in with facebook. This can be done using Javascript and the facebook API. Their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) provides a very detailed explanation with code examples etc. Note that i will explain for the case of Javascript, however, this could be done in php, ...

Once the user is logged in, you can retrieve all kind of information about the user, his pages, etc. I would suggest to retrieve the pages the user is managing, then check if your "company" is part of this list (note that you will need the *manage_pages* permission). If this is the case, the user can post a message in name of the page.

```
/* Retrieve pages the user is managing */
FB.api(
    "/me/accounts",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Now `response` is an object containing multiple fields (see the official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/)).

Now, if the user is an administrator of your page, you can post a message as a Page.

```
/* Post a message as a Page, use your page id */
FB.api(
    "/{page-id}/feed",
    "POST",
    {
        "message": "The match has been delayed to ..."
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

> If successful, the ID of the post will be returned as part of a JSON response (see [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed))